# Angular post request refused, but nodejs post request works

Tags: node.js, angular, post, production

I have an express app which listening on port 5000 like this:

```
app.listen(5000, "0.0.0.0, ()=>'Server started on' + 'port ' + 5000).
```

When i try to send a post request by node script using axios its response me 200.

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login', {})
```

But i when i try sending the same request using Angular HttpClient.Post its gives me an error : "Connection refused"

```
this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/auth/login', {username, password, role})
```

The problem started when i tried to run all of these components on a remote server.

it works for me fine when i tried to run all of these components on my local machine.

Any ideas why it should happen?

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you please check proxy settings for angular application ?

Comment: Where can i see it?

Comment: proxy.config.js and you can check proxyConfiguration in angular.json. Or if you have credentials in .npmrc file then you have to figure out how to configure auth setup in your application because when you run npm server it will consider npmrc file but angular will not consider this file while running the application as it is out of its context

Comment: I never configure it, just the default.

Comment: default port is 4200 for angular. can you please check with the port. It would be better if you share your code if possible.

Comment: I dont use .npmrc credentials.

Comment: When i use ng build, i get the compiled project, all i have to do i just serve it from an apache server?. When i try get 80, i really get my page, but it cant talk to the node server which listen on 5000.

Comment: What is the full response you get? "Connection refused" is somewhat vague. What HTTP response code are you getting? Is the request being successfully received by the API at least? What headers are being sent with the Axios request that may or may not be being sent with the Angular request? What is the content of `environment.apiUrl`? Many times I've accidentally left a trailing `/` on there, making my url invalid (`http://example.com/api//something`)...